# Can I access a constant value when creating a custom rule with typescript-eslint?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to add a custom ESLint rule using `@typescript-eslint/utils` to show a warning if the prop `kind` of `Category` doesn't match a Regex:

```
import { ESLintUtils, TSESTree } from '@typescript-eslint/utils'

const createRule = ESLintUtils.RuleCreator(() => '')

const rule = createRule({
   create(context) {
      return {
         'JSXOpeningElement[name.name="Category"] JSXAttribute[name.name="kind"]': (node: TSESTree.JSXAttribute) => {

           if (node.value?.type === 'Literal' && !/[A-Z]/.test(node.value.value)) {
              context.report({
                 node,
                 messageId: 'message'
              })
           }

      }
   },
   ...
})
```

The code above works as expected if I pass the prop as a string like in the first 2 cases, but I can't find a way to make it work if I pass a constant. Is it possible to access the value of `CATEGORY_C` from the `node`?

```
import { CATEGORY_C } from './constants'
import { Category } from './components/Category'

export const Categories () => (
   <>
      <Category kind='A' />
      <Category kind='B' />
      <Category kind={CATEGORY_C} />
   </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, yes! If you're trying to access the *type* of a node then the rule will need to be a [typed custom rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules#typed-rules).

Rephrasing the example from the docs of how to get the type of a node:

```
create(context) {
  return {
    'SomeSelector'(node) {
      const services = ESLintUtils.getParserServices(context);
      const type = services.getTypeAtLocation(node);

      // ...
    },
  };
}
```

That `type` is the `ts.Type` retrieved from the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)'s `getTypeAtLocation`.

Tip: you can preview nodes, types, and other rule info on typescript-eslint.io/play. See the *Types* tab for TypeScript type info for nodes. [This playground simulates the OP code snippet](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&showAST=types&fileType=.tsx&code=CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gYShkA5kjAJ4Bc8UKJA3AFB3LpbYCCAKgKIDiA8gEoBNAPrZ4AXngAibFPp0QADwAOxLE0w48hYgEsQaCfAAUASgkA%2BE3XjwAPBZu37ufEVLwA1rpTBxAclZ-eAB6R2cXbXcSLx8-fwAhYLCnWztXHQ9vX3EAbzYuPiFRAF9Q8PsU0wYgA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false).